# Magento 2 Order View Exception occurred during order load

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2

My Order detail page is not showing up its giving "Exception occurred during order load"
when i checked in logs i got Exception occurred during CURL call

```
 Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds at vendor/magento/framework/HTTP/Client/Curl.php:426
```

i am stuck in it. Please help.

Comment: May you please share your CURL code ?

Comment: Check the response of CURL.

Answer (score 0):

You are using CURL code so, please first test it with POSTMAN software if its working fine, then add the code in plain php, then try it in Magento 2.